# ARCore: random object rotation on vertical plane

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I managed to position a **3D model on a vertical plane** (using ARCore 1.4); it works well enough but the model is not in landscape starting position; instead, it starts randomly placed rotated, clockwise or counterclockwise (random degrees).

Is there a way to force it to start horizontally?

Comment: Are you creating an anchor for your 3D model ? If so what did you assign to anchor.rotation ?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating an anchor for my 3D model. But I'm not assigning any value to it. If I print the actual value of the anchor, I obtain the following values for rotation and position (at the first positioning of the object): 
`qx: 0.48500407,
qy: 0.48423967,
qz: 0.51455915,
qw: 0.5152785,
tx: 3.2918916,
ty: 0.14533181,
tz: 0.57555735`

Comment: Which pose did you use while creating your anchor.                                        public Anchor createAnchor (Pose pose)                                        
 If you detected the vertical plane, you have to get its pose from trackables and create your anchor for the 3D object using plane pose.rotation information. Position depends on you either do a hitresult or position it wherever you want on the plane.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it using your suggestions! I'll write the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

I've passed the `pose` object of the plane to the `createAnchor` method, in my `onTapArPlaneListener`.

Like this:

```
anchor = mySession.createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
```